# Firebird + JDBC: Getting the generated key from an insert

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, firebird

It looks like Firebird does NOT support getGeneratedKeys() after you perform an insert with an auto_increment column. So I would like to understand how I can get my hands on the generated key after an insert.

1) Do I have to use "insert into users(...) values(...) returning id" and call this through a CallableStatement in order to get the generated ID? How exactly? Do I need to wrap my insert around a "call { ... }"

2) Is there some other way of getting the generated id under Firebird, some kind of "select last_id_generated()". "select max(id) from users" does not count.

3) Is it really true that getGeneratedKeys() is not supported by Firebird JDBC driver? (optional)

Thanks!

Comment: This post might be helpful: http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/Firebird-Java/message/10170

Comment: Thanks but the post is kind of vague. It is not clear there how I can get that using JDBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that all you have to do is call the "insert ... returning" with executeQuery (from PreparedStatement) instead of executeUpdate. That will return your ResultSet from where you can get the generated id. I never thought that you could call an INSERT with executeQuery. I thought you had to do executeUpdate.

Comment: Firebird itself treats INSERT ... RETURNING <fields> as a query which produces a resultset. As getGeneratedKeys() is not (or not fully) implemented in Jaybird 2.1.6 (I will double check this tomorrow), using executeQuery() is a viable workaround as then it is simply treated like any other query which produces a resultset. Support for getGeneratedKeys() should be available in Jaybird 2.2 which will hopefully be released before the end of the year.

Comment: I checked and using executeQuery is the only way in Jaybird 2.1.6; getGeneratedKeys does work in Jaybird 2.2 (although there are still some bugs).

Answer (score 2):

**I am using construction to get primary key value:**

```
String buf =       
             "SELECT GEN_ID ( <YOUR_ID_NAME*>, 0 ) " + //see description below
             "FROM RDB$DATABASE";
try
{
    Statement stm = conn.createStatement ();
    ResultSet RS = stm.executeQuery ( buf );
    buf = null;
    if ( RS != null )
    {
        RS.next ();
        buf = RS.getString ( 1 ).trim (); //That is it
        RS.close ();
    }
}
catch ( SQLException e )
{}
```

**Now buf contains id**

`< *>`- You can see it with help IBExpert.

Answer (score 0):

Support for `getGeneratedKeys` was added in Jaybird 2.2. There are some caveats, the default `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` method will return **all** columns of the table, so you should retrieve columns from the result set by column name, or use one of the methods to explicitly specify the column index or column name, see the [Jaybird (2.2.7) release notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.7/release_notes.html#__RefHeading__6629_1850987433) for more details.

To answer your original questions:

1. When you execute `INSERT ... RETURNING ...`, you need to use `executeQuery` (or `execute`), and process the result set as if you are executing a normal `SELECT`. With Jaybird 2.2 you can also use `executeUpdate` if you are using `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` and obtain the result set from `getGeneratedKeys()`
2. Using `INSERT ... RETURNING ...` or `getGeneratedKeys` is the only way to get the generated value for that statement, all other methods (like `SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_NAME,0) FROM RDB$DATABASE`) cannot be trusted as sequences are outside of transaction control and the returned value might have been generated for a different concurrent transaction.
3. At the time you asked this question it was indeed not supported by Jaybird (2.1.6).

Disclosure: I am one of the developers of Jaybird.

Answer (score -1):

this will get the current generation

```
SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_NAME,0) FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

with GEN_NAME being what you called that generation

when you create a auto increment field a trigger and a generation is created the trigger looks like this usually

```
SET TERM ^^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER TABLE_BEFOREINSERT FOR TABLE ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0 AS
BEGIN

  if ( new.ID is null )
  then new.ID = gen_id(GEN_TABLE, 1);

END ^^
SET TERM ; ^^
```

and the creation for the generation looks like this

```
CREATE GENERATOR GEN_TABLE;
SET GENERATOR GEN_TABLE TO 32;
```

these two together make is so that BEFORE a new row is inserted, it checks to see if you specified the value of ID, if not it increases the generation by one and gets its current value and puts it as the ID column

Comment: Do i have to use returning? What do you mean by "what you called that generation"? That's an auto_increment field.

Comment: the above code is just a regualr sql statement just like the select max(id) from users example you wrote, you would get the result from it just like any other select statement. When you make a column an auto_increment field, the database creates a generation, usually named GEN_TABLE_NAME with GEN_ prefixing the table name

Comment: Firebird doesn't really have auto_increment field type like some other databases, the behavior is "faked" with triggers and generators. See more information here: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/ - I don't know how JDBC driver adapts to that model.

Comment: What the generation is called depends on how your are working with your tables, i use database workbench, and it automatically names them with the GEN_ prefix, other programs might name it differently. Also to clarify above, when you create and auto increment column, the database created a generation AND a before insert trigger that connects to that trigger, ill update my answer to explain better

Comment: Ok, so how do I get this ID through "insert ... returning", using JDBC? Do I use a CallableStatement? Do I have to wrap around a "call { ... }" ? Do I have to use registerOutParameter?

Comment: I believe the JDBC driver for firebird doesn't support the returning clause, thats what I seem to be finding when looking around. Either getting the ID using the above statement after you insert, or getting the ID before inserting, and using it in your insert statement would be your best bet it seems like

Comment: What a curse to have to use Firebird. I am doing this so I can support Firebird on [MentaBean](http://mentabean.soliveirajr.com).

Comment: I love firebird, but I use it with php, and I haven't run into anything that I cant do with it on php. But maybe someone else that knows java better might have another answer for ya.

Comment: As generators are outside transaction control, it is a very bad idea to select the current value of the generator and assume it is the value that was used for the last insert in your own transaction.